# Angular Routing in IIS server

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, web-config

I have an Angular 4 app in a IIS server, in the same server there is a .NET Web API. They are in diferents folders: angular app is in "/wwwroot/angular/" and web api in "/wwwroot/api/". When I do a request to web api, it works successfully, but when I try to navigate to an URL different to index.html using the Routing Module in angular app I get this message:

[500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA3Au.png)

Also, I have two Web.Config files -one in each folder-.

My Angular Web. Config is:

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
   </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Web.config of WEB API

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I researched in some questions like:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/49833141/blank-page-when-publishing-angular-5-net-core-web-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833141/blank-page-when-publishing-angular-5-net-core-web-api)

and

[stackoverflow.com/questions/42865084/redirect-unknown-requests-to-index-html-in-springboot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865084/redirect-unknown-requests-to-index-html-in-springboot)

But they doesn't work to me.

Anybody help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your Route file in Webapi ?

Comment: You need to redirect every request except the assets like images etc. to the `index.html`.

Comment: @Niladri I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was move all the Angular files to root, at index.html I left `<base href="/">` and make the web.config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="^(.*)$" />
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Route" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/api(.*)$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config change  `<action type="Rewrite" url="/FIN360" />` and in your index.html from the `<base href="/">` remove the **/** Try this else change `<base href="./">` OR `<base href="/FIN360">`

Comment: Do I deploy with `ng build --prod`, whitout `--base-href=/FIN360/`?

Comment: I get the same message: 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: build it with ng build --prod -base-href=/FIN360 and do restart your application pool in iis and post that do the rewuest in incognito window or clear the cache of the browser.

Comment: I did it, but I've a new problem, like this: [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184300/iis-configuration-for-using-angular-ui-routing-html5mode)

Comment: @MikeGsus I have answered on that question itself